# Flask request.remote_addr is wrong on webfaction and not showing real user IP

Tags: python, flask, webfaction

I just deployed a Flask app on Webfaction and I've noticed that `request.remote_addr` is always `127.0.0.1`. which is of course isn't of much use.

How can I get the real IP address of the user in Flask on Webfaction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If there is a proxy in front of Flask, then something like this will get the real IP in Flask:

```
if request.headers.getlist("X-Forwarded-For"):
   ip = request.headers.getlist("X-Forwarded-For")[0]
else:
   ip = request.remote_addr
```

**Update:** Very good point mentioned by Eli in his comment. There could be some security issues if you just simply use this. Read [Eli's post](http://esd.io/blog/flask-apps-heroku-real-ip-spoofing.html) to get more details.

Comment: This is dangerous advice. Webfaction *appends* the real address to X-Forwarded-For so using this code -- which selects the first address in the list -- lets a malicious user spoof their IP address to *any arbitrary string*. See http://esd.io/blog/flask-apps-heroku-real-ip-spoofing.html for longer discussion and my attempt at a solution.

Comment: Very good point Eli. Adding the note to the answer with the link to your post.

Comment: Not so sure about that. http://docs.webfaction.com/software/django/troubleshooting.html#accessing-remote-addr   (it looks like it uses [0], but your point is still correct just not for webfaction I think)

Comment: You don't want to access `x-forwarded-for` directly. Flask and werkzeug provide [`request.access_route`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.access_route) which contains the already-split IP list from that header.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: If I apply the Werkzeug ProxyFix then request.access_route will still give me the spoofed IP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868900/how-do-i-safely-get-the-users-real-ip-address-in-flask-using-mod-wsgi

Comment: Using Nginx, now it gives X-Real-Ip instead of X-Forwarded-For

Answer (score 16):

## Werkzeug middleware

Flask's documentation is pretty specific [about recommended reverse proxy server setup](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#proxy-setups):

> If you deploy your application using one of these [WSGI] servers behind an HTTP [reverse] proxy you will need to rewrite a few headers in order for the application to work [properly]. The two problematic values in the WSGI environment usually are `REMOTE_ADDR` and `HTTP_HOST`... Werkzeug ships a fixer that will solve some common setups, but you might want to write your own WSGI middleware for specific setups.

And also about security consideration:

> Please keep in mind that it is a security issue to use such a middleware in a non-proxy setup because it will blindly trust the incoming headers which might be forged by malicious clients.

The suggested code (that installs the middleware) that will make `request.remote_addr` return client IP address is:

```
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app, num_proxies=1)
```

Note `num_proxies` which is `1` by default. It's *the number of proxy servers in front of the app*.

The actual code is as follows (lastest `werkzeug==0.14.1` at the time of writing):

```
def get_remote_addr(self, forwarded_for):
    if len(forwarded_for) >= self.num_proxies:
        return forwarded_for[-self.num_proxies]
```

## Webfaction

Webfaction's documentation about [Accessing `REMOTE_ADDR`](https://docs.webfaction.com/software/django/troubleshooting.html#accessing-remote-addr) says:

> ...the IP address is available as the first IP address in the comma separated list in the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` header.

They don't say what they do when a client request already contains `X-Forwarded-For` header, but following common sense I would assume they replace it. Thus for Webfaction `num_proxies` should be set to `0`.

## Nginx

Nginx is more explicit about it's [`$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#var_proxy_add_x_forwarded_for):

> the “X-Forwarded-For” client request header field with the `$remote_addr` variable appended to it, separated by a comma. If the “X-Forwarded-For” field is not present in the client request header, the `$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for` variable is equal to the `$remote_addr` variable.

For Nginx in front of the app `num_proxies` should be left at default `1`.

Comment: If yuo're running werkzeug 1.0.0 you need to import `from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix` instead.

Comment: The arguments have also changed. Up-to-date documentation can be found here: https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/middleware/proxy_fix/

Answer (score 7):

Rewriting the Ignas's answer:

```
headers_list = request.headers.getlist("X-Forwarded-For")
user_ip = headers_list[0] if headers_list else request.remote_addr
```

Remember to read [Eli's post](http://esd.io/blog/flask-apps-heroku-real-ip-spoofing.html) about spoofing considerations.

Comment: Yes the code is more beautiful (mine was more newbie friendly :D) but it still has the same issues mentioned already by the other guys, so be careful.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `request.access_route` to access list of ip :

```
if len(request.access_route) > 1:
    return request.access_route[-1]
else:
    return request.access_route[0]
```

Update:

You can just write this:

```
    return request.access_route[-1]
```

Comment: You don't actually need the length check here -- `some_list[-1] == some_list[0]` on single length lists

Comment: It's not single length list. it may have more than one item in it.

Comment: @itmard I think @tristan's point is that the last item is always accessible for lists with >= 1 items. So code can always written as `request.access_route[-1]` to get the last IP in the list.

Comment: If you are behind for example proxy server this list has more than one value. this is why this is a list not just a string.

Comment: Useless use of length check, as @tristan pointed out. Your `else` would only match if the length is 1 (Flask will always return at least one result.), which `request.access_route[-1]` would still be valid for.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is there's probably some kind of proxy in front of Flask. In this case the "real" IP address can often be found in `request.headers['X-Forwarded-For']`.

Comment: Good tip, I used that and got solution. Posting it as an answer.