# How do I safely get the user's real IP address in Flask (using mod_wsgi)?

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I have a flask app setup on mod_wsgi/Apache and need to log the IP Address of the user. request.remote_addr returns "127.0.0.1" and [this fix](http://esd.io/blog/flask-apps-heroku-real-ip-spoofing.html) attempts to correct that but I've found that Django removed similar code for security reasons.

Is there a better way to safely get the user's real IP address?

EDIT: Maybe I'm missing something obvious. I applied [werkzeug's/Flask's fix](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/contrib/fixers.py#L94-144) but it doesn't seem to make a difference when I try a request with altered headers:

run.py:

```
    from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix
    app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
    app.run()
```

view.py:

```
for ip in request.access_route:
        print ip # prints "1.2.3.4" and "my.ip.address"
```

This same result happens if I have the ProxyFix enabled or not. I feel like I'm missing something completely obvious

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the [`request.access_route` attribute](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.access_route) only if you define a list of *trusted* proxies.

The `access_route` attribute uses the [`X-Forwarded-For` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For), falling back to the `REMOTE_ADDR` WSGI variable; the latter is fine as your server determines this; the `X-Forwarded-For` could have been set by just about anyone, but if you trust a proxy to set the value correctly, then use the first one (from the end) that is *not* trusted:

```
trusted_proxies = {'127.0.0.1'}  # define your own set
route = request.access_route + [request.remote_addr]

remote_addr = next((addr for addr in reversed(route) 
                    if addr not in trusted_proxies), request.remote_addr)
```

That way, even if someone spoofs the `X-Forwarded-For` header with `fake_ip1,fake_ip2`, the proxy server will add `,spoof_machine_ip` to the end, and the above code will set the `remote_addr` to `spoof_machine_ip`, no matter how many trusted proxies there are in addition to your outermost proxy.

This is the whitelist approach your linked article talks about (briefly, in that Rails uses it), and what [Zope implemented over 11 years ago](https://github.com/zopefoundation/Zope/commit/ee35841ba2209a037c6aafdc5b25f0aa7d6674d6).

Your ProxyFix approach works just fine, but you misunderstood what it does. It *only* sets `request.remote_addr`; the `request.access_route` attribute is unchanged (the `X-Forwarded-For` header is *not* adjusted by the middleware). *However*, I'd be very wary of blindly counting off proxies.

Applying the same whitelist approach to the middleware would look like:

```
class WhitelistRemoteAddrFix(object):
    """This middleware can be applied to add HTTP proxy support to an
    application that was not designed with HTTP proxies in mind.  It
    only sets `REMOTE_ADDR` from `X-Forwarded` headers.

    Tests proxies against a set of trusted proxies.

    The original value of `REMOTE_ADDR` is stored in the WSGI environment
    as `werkzeug.whitelist_remoteaddr_fix.orig_remote_addr`.

    :param app: the WSGI application
    :param trusted_proxies: a set or sequence of proxy ip addresses that can be trusted.
    """

    def __init__(self, app, trusted_proxies=()):
        self.app = app
        self.trusted_proxies = frozenset(trusted_proxies)

    def get_remote_addr(self, remote_addr, forwarded_for):
        """Selects the new remote addr from the given list of ips in
        X-Forwarded-For.  Picks first non-trusted ip address.
        """

        if remote_addr in self.trusted_proxies:
            return next((ip for ip in reversed(forwarded_for)
                         if ip not in self.trusted_proxies),
                        remote_addr)

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        getter = environ.get
        remote_addr = getter('REMOTE_ADDR')
        forwarded_for = getter('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', '').split(',')
        environ.update({
            'werkzeug.whitelist_remoteaddr_fix.orig_remote_addr': remote_addr,
        })
        forwarded_for = [x for x in [x.strip() for x in forwarded_for] if x]
        remote_addr = self.get_remote_addr(remote_addr, forwarded_for)
        if remote_addr is not None:
            environ['REMOTE_ADDR'] = remote_addr
        return self.app(environ, start_response)
```

To be explicit: this middleware too, *only* sets `request.remote_addr`; `request.access_route` remains unaffected.

Answer (score -4):

You can't safely do that, because the you can't trust all the parts in a http (or tcp) connection

Comment: You can trust your own server to set the ip address of the remote connection correctly. You can choose to trust specific remote connections to tell the truth. Combined with a whitelist, you can build a chain of trust.

Comment: And what about ip-spoofing or malicious proxies.?

Comment: IP spoofing in a TCP/IP connection requires that you can sniff the packets; e.g. you can also intercept whatever goes up and down already. Malicious proxies shouldn't be added to your trusted list, *duh*.