# Get public client IP in a Flask App?

Tags: flask, mod-wsgi

I want to log the public WAN IP of a client trying to authenticate on a Flask application.

Actually, any method I tried return me the LAN IP of the client.

My stack is an Apache 2.2 server using mod_wsgi to serve the Flask application.

Methods I tried :

```
request.remote_addr
request.access_route # The list contain only one value which is the LAN IP
request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

How could I get the public IP ?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT uniqueness:

I have no proxy set and don't have the "X-Forwarded-For" header.

I don't get a "127.0.0.1" but the LAN IP of the client.

For exemple, for the moment my LAN IP is "10.192.132.148" and my colleague LAN IP could be "10.192.132.149", but our public WAN IP is for both "193.xxx.xxx.xxx".

I'm looking for a way to get this last one in my Flask application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I safely get the user's real IP address in Flask (using mod\_wsgi)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868900/how-do-i-safely-get-the-users-real-ip-address-in-flask-using-mod-wsgi)

Comment: Ähm... if you, your collegue AND your webserver are on the same subnet, there is no way to get a public ip address, because the server doesn't see it at any point.

Comment: The webserver is not on our subnet, it is hosted somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I got the explication ... the test server was visible only via a connection through a VPN network, so the server was seeing my computer directly just like if it was on my LAN.