# Get IP Address of Request in Flask App on Glitch.com

Tags: python, flask, ip, ip-address, glitch-framework

I have a Flask App running on [Glitch](https://glitch.com). I want to find a way to get the IP address of the client who is requesting data from my website. Is there a way to do that? And before you mark this question as a duplicate, I tried `request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']`, `request.environ.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP', request.remote_addr)`, `request.remote_addr`, and so many more. All of those show 127.0.0.1, which is the server's IP Address. I am looking for a specific way on Glitch. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
# Imports

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    # Stuff

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't why `remote_addr` didn't work, did you use it this way:

```
# Imports
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
     ipdr = {'ipdr': request.remote_addr}
     return jsonify(ipdr), 200

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run()
```

Comment: Yes I did use it that way. I will try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868900/how-do-i-safely-get-the-users-real-ip-address-in-flask-using-mod-wsgi and see if that works next